# CPLEX with logical if/else operation

Tags: mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, cplex

I am new CPLEX user. I have a question, can I use if/else logical operation in CPLEX? (not inside the constraint).

Comment: I assume you're talking about mathematical programming here.  What API are you using?  E.g., C++, .NET, Python, etc.?  Or, are you referring to the OPL modeling language?  If you're not talking about logical constraints, then what do you want to do exactly?  Can you provide an example or pseudocode?

Comment: What problem (e.g. inventory, resource allocation) are you trying to model and solve? Usually it's modeling question rather than coding. For instance, one can use binary variables to model if-else statement, e.g., `a*x+b*(1-x)`, if `x=1` then `a` else `b`

Answer (score 0):

From your question is not clear whether you're using CPLEX OPL or a CPLEX interface to a programming language like C++, C#, Java, Matlab, and so on. You could tell us and next responses will be less *generic*.

Let us assume you're testing an if a variable `x` is equal to `1`. In positive case you would use an inequality `model_ineq_1`, otherwise `model_ineq_2` should be used. The following expression should work in all cases:

```
(x == 1) ? model_ineq_1 : model_ineq_2
```

As you can see it tests `(condition_happens) ? do_this_if_true : do_this_if_false`. It is actually called ternary operator and it provides an inline if-then-else statement.